# Apply different style to whitespace between words using CSS

Tags: css

I've got a block of regular text inside a div.  I'd like to use CSS to apply style to the words themselves, but not the whitespace between them.

For example, let's say I have this passage of text:

```
 The dog barked.
```

I would want to style the three words with a background color, but then not style the space between the words.

Is this even possible?  I feel like I'll probably have to break up the words into individual 's and do it that way, but I'd rather add any markup to the text.

Comment: to change the font size keeping the space among the words, you can use `word-spacing: Xpx;`

Comment: AFAIK there is no CSS selector for spaces

Comment: the only way is if you add each word inside a span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible with CSS alone. Using JavaScript you could split the string and apply spans to the text to style them differently, but nothing in CSS alone will do what you want.